# Can't parent mesh to Armature

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

So, for some prior context, I'm trying to rig a model I had previously sculpted, but it doesn't seem the mesh will parent onto the armature no matter what I try. I've selected both, ctrl+p, set parent, with automatic weights, then tried setting it manually in the armature.

However, this is my first attempt at rigging and it may be an easy fix.

I'd love if someone could give me a hand. Thanks!

[image]

[Blend on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zsuFIYJ_zCz9ScC5RLHS7tjfl_CBUOFw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the armature, you can see that you've parented it to the mesh, an object can't be both parent and child of another object, so deactivate the parentage. Also you'll need to remove doubles in your mesh (select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*), otherwise you won't be able to parent it.

[image]

Comment: This worked! I followed your advice, and also double checked to make sure I was parenting it properly, and it's rigged now. Thank you very much, and thank you especially for such a fast reply!